# Formatting DateTime in .NET Core React app

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

I am new to .NET Core and am exploring creating applications with a React frontend and .NET back end. I am starting very simple and at the moment am just trying to format the DateTime. The relevant files are:

DateController.cs:

```
 public class DateController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet, Route("GetDate")]
        public async Task<string> GetDate()
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            string format = "MMM ddd d HH:mm yyyy"; 
            string info = $"Today is {dt.ToString(format)}";
            return info; 
        }
    }
```

Date.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class Date extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: "" };

    fetch("api/Date/GetDate")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ date: data });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <h1>{this.state.date} </h1>;
  }
}
```

However, the date doesn't seem to be formatted as I am expecting, as it displays in the browser like this (and even misses the "Today is..." part:

"Sun Aug 18 2019 21:30:24 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)".

Can anyone please guide me as to where I have gone wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it even missing the "Today is " part?

Comment: @DanielEarwicker Yes, it is - I can't work out what has gone wrong

Comment: What is going on with the '$' on line, string info = $"Today is {dt.ToString(format)}";

Comment: @MatthewE.Miller I understood that this was how to use string interpolation in C# (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) but I am very new to C# so please feel free to correct me if wrong!

Comment: @jordantomiko the interpolation looks fine. From what you’re saying I can only guess that your code is not rebuilding when you change it so you’re calling some old version from before you added the custom date formatting?

Comment: Remove the `Route("GetDate")` attribute and see if that makes any difference.  Also, there's nothing `async` about your `GetDate` method, so no reason to add the complexity of an async method.

Comment: @Corey @DanielEarwicker thank you for your advice. It turns out it was to do with this line `{this.state.date}` displaying React's date object rather than speaking to my .NET function on the backend. I have fixed :)

Comment: @Corey Removing `async` caused the following error: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string>"

Comment: Change the method signature to `public string GetDate()` - returning `Task<string>` is part of the `async` signature.

Answer (score 1):

here all patterns of the dateTime class, but I don't see your pattern among them
[image]

Comment: thank you for this! It turns out it was to do with this line `{this.state.date}` displaying React's date object rather than speaking to my .NET function on the backend. I have fixed :) But I have used this list to correctly format my DateTime object so thank you

Comment: really glad, if I helped you.Can you mark answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

I still prefer to see the date in numbers is much easy to render in Client JS/React/Angular

```
        var currentTime = new DateTime(2019, 8, 19, 1, 0, 0, 100, DateTimeKind.Utc);
        var value = currentTime.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc));
        Console.WriteLine($"Unix Time With Milliseconds: {value.TotalMilliseconds}");
```

Comment: thank you for your advice. It turns out it was to do with this line `{this.state.date}` displaying React's date object rather than speaking to my .NET function on the backend. I have fixed :)